# How to set modelValue in Angular formly using custom template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I have create custom template to add todo list in angular formly. [jsbin Link](http://jsbin.com/dunoxamezo/edit?output)

I'm trying to add required validation but its not working. I have added validators to check. But viewValue, modelValue contains value in input field. Is there are any way to set modelValue in validator with actual model.

```
 return [
    {
      className: 'col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12',
      key: 'todoList',
      type: 'todolist',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Add todo list',
        placeholder: 'Enter todo list'
      },
      validators: {
        tagLength: {
          expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {                                 
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;
            console.log(modelValue)
            console.log(viewValue)
            //return value.length > 0;
          },
          message: '"Altest 1 Operation is required"'
        }
      }

    }
```

What i'm exactly trying to achive is, if todolist is empty then submit button should be disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unnecessary.  All you have to do is set the ng-show in the submit button.  No validators are needed.  Just tested it on your jsbin link and it works as expected.  Please mark this as the correct answer.

```
ng-show="vm.model.todoList.length > 0" OR
ng-show="vm.model.todoList" (since it will be false if empty/undefined)
```

Validators are to validate the input on THAT field, not for other fields/buttons.

Comment: thanks for answer. Above work around works fine when their is only 1 todoList in form. But its not working when i have "repeat section" (repeat section is angular formly template which adds new form feild section from existing form feild section) of todolist.

Comment: You can simply get the length of the todoList index then check each one.  If there is a value in any of them set a flag to true, if not, the flag stays false and just use ng-show to check against the flag value.  It's still the same concept.